# When to consider base64 (DATA: URI) images?

Tags: css, image, base64

What are the factors that should trigger thinking about switching images over to Base64 embedded in CSS?

There seems to be a lot of generic pro/con type things out there. Wikipedia seems to have a decent overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Advantages

From what I've read, the one factor that seems to make base64 an easy decision would be if your site has to access a lot of individual small images and having one large file would be more efficient that hitting the server 50 times for each individual image.

But...it also seems that with sprites and the fact that rarely would I need 50 separate images on a page, Base64 isn't offering a whole lot for general web sites.

Are there are key factors I should be looking for (both pro/con)?

(This may better as a community wiki entry rather than question)

UPDATE:

Perhaps a more succinct way to word the question:

Given these two options:

1) All images converted to base64 and embedded in the external css file

2) Images gathered into a handful of sprite images, referenced in the external css file

Are there obvious situations where one is better than the other, or is it really just a case-by-case, do both and test type of thing?

Comment: This is not really about *base64* images, but about the `data:` URI scheme (which usually entails base64 encoding but isn't identical with it). I would edit the question accordingly, it's slightly misleading at the moment.

Comment: Pekka: I'd be glad to edit it. Could you help me understand how it should be reworded? Should the title actually refer to data: instead of base64?

Answer (score 6):

> Are there are key factors I should be looking for (both pro/con)?

The biggest con is the missing support in IE6/7, and the incomplete support in IE8 (`data:` URIs must not be larger than 32 kilobytes there).

Using CSS sprites is the vastly superior technique in this case.

Comment: In a very rare case in the history of my career...IE is actually not even on the table (we're doing this for a mobile device--though I assume sooner or later they'll want to support win7 phones) though it is certainly the key factor in most situations.

Comment: @DA.: Note that massive sprite sheets are not supported on iPhone.

Comment: @DA depends on your career (I'm jealous) I have to deal with IE6 still a LOT in 2013 ! cause of the big corporate clients glued to it with bespoke apps plus brain dead IT depts (or outsourced IT). not fun. lucky you, but in big corporate intranet world its still 2001 ;(

Answer (score 3):

There are two different issues here:

1) base 64. Well there's no advantage here. The files are fatter than binary and are less likely to be cached. Resources should be in external files so they can be cached.

2) Sprites. CSS sprites are a technique where a single image is used instead of multiple ones. Portions of the image are "revealed" via CSS. These are more efficient because the number of network requests are greatly reduced. It's worth it.

Comment: I may need to reword the question. I guess what it comes down to is comparing the two...Base64 encoded images in one CSS file vs. leveraging sprites. Is there a strong reason to pick one over the other in various situations?

Comment: Ah, I get it. I guess you'd need to benchmark it. Depending on the size and number of your images + decode time vs. just using images.

Comment: ??? but css could / should be cached also... so ??? if your talking extra requests for sprites (cached or not) vs embedded data uri images... in cached css... then TOTALLY DEPENDS on context but not obviously sprites winning. depends on details of the context

Comment: Sprite technique limits your options how you align and scale images in your layout. Win for base64 here: can easily use background-size prop, align using left/center/right on any axis.

Comment: @Haradzieniec : now take that sprite and fill a relatively sized element where, say, width is a fraction of body width and body width can change (different mobile screen sizes + orientation change).

Comment: @Tadas Sasnauskas: Oh, I see... That's a good question. Thank you for pointing that.

Answer (score 0):

When you can use css-sprites, that's definitely better.

One particular case in which I prefer base64 DATA URI is when we have a small image file which will be used as background with repeat-x or repeat-y. Since repeat doesn't play well with css-sprites, you need to use a single image as a source. In this case, I find that using the base64 version is a better alternative which saves you a request to your web server.